# d3 dateformat parse returns null

Tags: d3.js

I am using d3.time.format to parse a time variable. But the parsed_date returns null value.

```
date = "Thu Apr 18 09:06:23 +0000 2019"
dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d")
parsed_date = dateFormat.parse(date)
```

I expect

```
parsed_date to return "2019-04-18"
```

Comment: Which version of D3 are you using? I think v4 and up uses `timeFormat` rather than `time.format`

Comment: @Charlie it's  >> version: "3.5.17"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.parse` method allows to convert date as string to native JavaScript date format. After that you can format the date as you want, so you should rewrite you code this way to make it works:

```js
const date = "Thu Apr 18 09:06:23 +0000 2019";

const parseFunc = d3.time.format("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y").parse;
const formatFunc = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");

const parsed_date = formatFunc(parseFunc(date));

console.log(parsed_date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```